# Deadlocks with Play 2.5 scala, deadbolt 2.5 and MongoDB/Morphia

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, scala, playframework

Basically all I want to do is getting all users from my database, which worked fine until the very moment i wanted to use deadbolt for it:

I think the 4 Threads(number of processors) of the  fork-join-executor are already all used and then there is somekind of deadlock.
Things I tried:

- Raise the number of threads the executor has, so however play/akka ignores my settings
- Define another execution context for the futures in the controller, but this does not prevent deadlocks since more than four threads still wait at each other
- use a thread-pool-executor, but my settings are ignored

A mixed scala/java code from here:

```
class UserController {
     def getUserList = deadbolt.Restrict(List(Array("Admin")))(){ implicit request =>
        Future {
          val users = userModel.list
          val json = Json.toJson(users)
          Ok(json.toString)
        }(
      }
}
```

The User Model is essentially nothing more than:

```
public class UserModel {
  private MongoClient client  = new MongoClient();
    private Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
    protected Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, "timetracking");
    public List<User> list(){
       return  datastore.find(User.class).asList();
    }
  public User findUserByName(String name){
    User found = datastore.createQuery(User.class).field("username").equal(name).get();
    return found;
    }
}
```

Authorization Handler:

```
class AuthorizationHandler extends DeadboltHandler {
  val model = new UserModel

  override def getSubject[A](request: AuthenticatedRequest[A]): Future[Option[Subject]] =
    Future {
      blocking {
        request.subject match {
          case Some(user) =>
            request.subject
          case None =>
            val username = request.session.get("username")
            if (username.isDefined) {
              val user = model.findUserByName(username.get)
              if (user == null) {
                  None
              } else {
                val subject = new ScalaSubject(user.getUsername, user.getRole)
                Some(subject)
              }
            } else {
              None
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Defining a seperate deadbolt context does not help:

```
package deadbolt.scala
import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.DeadboltExecutionContextProvider
import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.cache.HandlerCache
import play.api.inject.{Binding, Module}
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}

class DeadBoldModule extends Module {
  override def bindings(environment: Environment,
                        configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]] = Seq(
      bind[HandlerCache].to[TimeTrackerHandelCache],
      bind[DeadboltExecutionContextProvider].to[ThreadPoolProvider]
  )
}
```

Custom context provider:

```
package deadbolt.scala
import java.io.InvalidObjectException
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.DeadboltExecutionContextProvider
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class ThreadPoolProvider  extends DeadboltExecutionContextProvider {
  override def get(): ExecutionContext =  ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100))
}
```

When I try this, throwing some random exception, it is never thrown:

```
package deadbolt.scala
import java.io.InvalidObjectException
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.DeadboltExecutionContextProvider
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class ThreadPoolProvider  extends DeadboltExecutionContextProvider {
  override def get(): ExecutionContext = throw new IllegalAccessError("asd");ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100))
}
```

Comment: What happens if you give Deadbolt its own execution context?  See https://deadbolt-scala.readme.io/docs/execution-context for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I updated the question. It does not seem to help.
The http request still sometimes never finishes, which it does if I remove the deadbolt security check. Maybe I declared the Context Provider in the wrong way?

By the Way: the standard deadbolt modul binds this:
bind[ExecutionContextProvider].to[DefaultExecutionContextProvider],

Not DeadboltExecutionContextProvider.

Comment: I know - it provides a default DeadboltExecutionContextProvider in case a custom one isn't bound. Odd that your exception isn't thrown; try adding a breakpoint to https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/scala/ExecutionContextProvider.scala#L42 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not deadbolts fault, but however the MongoClient opened a new thread when it was instantiated.Which happened in our project quite often, but was not closed properly thereby blocking the threadpool. We used a Singleton and everything worked fine.